# Can you do anything after moving into an occupied space?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, actions

This is inspired by and is a branching off of the question "[Move into nonhostile space attack and move](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/76145)"

---

The section on "[Moving Around Other Creatures](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MovingAroundOtherCreatures)" states:

> [...] Whether a creature is a friend or an enemy, you can't willingly **end your move** in its space [...]

The is also the following unofficial ruling ([tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/727600681079595009)) from lead game designer Jeremy Crawford:

> Q. Can a character move into a space occupied by their ally, make an attack from that space, and then move away?
>
> A. You can't willingly stop moving in another creature's space.

Both the question mentioned at the beginning and the Crawford quote explain that you cannot move into an occupied space, **make an attack**, and move away; however, perhaps there are other things you could do instead? Basically, what counts as "ending your move"?

**Can you do any of the following *after* moving into an occupied space but *before* leaving it?**

- Take any sort of action
- Take any sort of bonus action
- Take any sort of reaction
- Do something that requires no action whatsoever, such as talking, or dropping concentration

---

To limit this question a bit, I would like answers to assume that the movement into the occupied space is *willing* movement.

Comment: Good question, and there may be a difference between willing action and unwilling, such as entering a square as part of a move and being hit with an effect that ends movement.

Comment: @SeriousBri It's discussed in the following questions: "[What happens when your movement is set to zero while attempting to move through a friendly space?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105393)" and "[Does the rule that you cannot willingly end your move in another creature's space force or prevent certain actions?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/153447)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## You cannot move into an occupied space, you can only move through it

Your question is besides the point. It is not possible to ever be in an occupied space.

[Moving Around Other Creatures](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MovingAroundOtherCreatures)

> **You can move through a nonhostile creature's space**. In contrast, you can move through a hostile creature's space only if the creature is at least two sizes larger or smaller than you. Remember that another creature's space is difficult terrain for you.
>
> Whether a creature is a friend or an enemy, **you can't willingly end your move in its space**.

You can move through an occupied space, but you cannot stop there.

The rules for [Breaking Up Your Move](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#BreakingUpYourMove) state:

> You can break up your movement on your turn, using some of your speed before and after your action. For example, if you have a speed of 30 feet, you can **move** 10 feet, take your action, and then **move** 20 feet.

You can break up your movement into various smaller movements. However, these smaller moves still have to follow all the movement rules. You can see the rules are very careful to treat them as normal moves.

Even if you only move 10ft you can still only move *through* occupied spaces, and you still cannot end your move in an occupied space.

If you somehow manage to end up here (non-willingly), then yes you can do whatever.

One exception is [object interaction](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#OtherActivityonYourTurn):

> You can also interact with one object or feature of the environment for free, during either your move or your action.

It is explicitly stated that you can interact with an object while moving.

Comment: Could you support that doing something such as talking or dropping concentration counts as "ending your move"?

Comment: @Medix2 I think that is a confusing question. Once you have stop moving you end your move. It doesn't matter what you stop moving to do, if you stop then you stop. The exception I can think of is free object interaction since it states "You can also interact with one object or feature of the environment for free, **during** either your move". There is no such provision to communicate or end concentration while moving.

Comment: The object interaction rule just seems to say the same as how attacks work, with an additional note that you can interact mid attack. It doesn't look like proof to me

Comment: The fact that object interaction occurs simultaneous with your movement is further supported by the Interacting with Objects around you Sidebar, which says "Here are a few examples of the sorts of thing you can do **in tandem** with your movement and action:"

Answer (score 0):

### Yes you can

The rules [say](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MovementandPosition):

> **Movement and Position**
>
> On your turn, you can move a distance up to your speed. You can use as much or as little of your speed as you like on your turn, following the rules here.

[and](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#BreakingUpYourMove):

> **Breaking Up Your Move**
>
> You can break up your movement on your turn, using some of your speed before and after your action. For example, if you have a speed of 30 feet, you can move 10 feet, take your action, and then move 20 feet.
>
> **Moving Between Attacks**
>
> If you take an action that includes more than one weapon attack, you can break up your movement even further by moving between those attacks. For example, a fighter who can make two attacks with the Extra Attack feature and who has a speed of 25 feet could move 10 feet, make an attack, move 15 feet, and then attack again.

[and](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MovingAroundOtherCreatures):

> **Moving Around Other Creatures**
>
> Whether a creature is a friend or an enemy, you can't willingly end your move in its space.

The rules permit you to insert your action into your movement anywhere and prohibit you from willingly finishing your movement in another creature's space. They are silent on using your action while within another creature's space so we should adopt [this](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/857269923134939136) tweet:

> Beware of claims that a rule does something mentioned nowhere in that rule or elsewhere in the core books. There aren't secret rules.

I am aware of this [tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/727635129321984001?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw) which is just such a claim so I will beware of it.

[Sage Advice](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf) continues to remain silent on the matter.

Therefore, you can take any (bonus) action while sharing another creature's space providing you do not willingly remain there.