# Can a Boggle use the optional rule to Tumble to Oil Puddle a creatures space?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

The Boggle creature has an action that can lay down a sticky oil that covers the ground in the Boggle's space. In the DMG(p272) there are rules to Tumble, which lets you move through the enemy space once if you succeed.

Using them together could the Boggle use it's Oil Puddle during it's movement through their space?

Comment: Related, possibly answers your question: [Can you do anything after moving into an occupied space?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/159761/can-you-do-anything-after-moving-into-an-occupied-space)

Comment: Wouldn't the action be limited to either before or after the tumbling move?   So either Oil Puddle, then Tumble, or Tumble, then Oil Puddle.  Neither of those would allow Oil Puddle during the Tumble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The actions work out at least**

Tumble and Overrun can be attempted as an action or bonus action so the Boggle could Bonus Action tumble, win the contested check and move through the space, still having its Action available to do the Oil Puddle.

That part is fairly clear. But... the Tumble and Overrun description say:

> If the tumbler wins the contest, it can move through the hostile creature's space once this turn.

That implies that the space being moved through is NOT the Boggle's space to control and therefore Oil Puddle can't be used.

That's RAW anyway, of course DM fiat and rule of cool can easily affect that.